# Is it okay to declare `// ignore: must_be_immutable` on a class?

Tags: flutter, dart, oop, dart-null-safety

I'm getting this error on a class that extends [Equatable](https://pub.dev/packages/equatable)

```
This class (or a class that this class inherits from) is marked as '@immutable', 
but one or more of its instance fields aren't final:
```

I want to have a `named` constructor alongside a regular unnamed constructor, but if I declare all the properties of my class as `final` it won't be possible, because the named constructor will only initialize some parameters on the class.

For context, here's a similar problem;

```
class Parent extends Equatable{
  final String id;
  final String name;

  Parent(this.id, this.name);

  // Error: All final variables must be initialized
  Parent.list(
      this.id
      );
  
  @override
  List<Object?> get props => [id, name];
}
```

One solution is to declare the fields, that are not required in the named constructor as `late`, but then it again throws the same warning as above.

Comment: Needing to initialize members has to do with them being non-nullable.  It has nothing to do with them being `final`.  If you want `name` to be optional, it either should be nullable or you should initialize it to a sentinel value (e.g. the empty string) if it is unused.

Answer (score 2):

You can designate the name field `name` as nullable and initialize it as `null` in the constructor

```dart
class Parent extends Equatable{
  final String id;
  final String? name;

  Parent(this.id, this.name);

  Parent.list(this.id) : name = null;

  @override
  List<Object?> get props => [id, name];
}
```

Comment: Or instead of making it nullable assign it empty string for example like `Parent.list(this.id) : name = "";`